# How to create an image that is just shading and transparency?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency, png

In photoshop I created this image that is supposed to represent the folds of a curtain:

[image: image with shading]

I, however, only want the shading aspect of this so that I can export that to a PNG and display it over any color on the Web.

So my question then is how do I get only the shading part of this image into a PNG?

Comment: Hello Eric, I edited your question for clarity. If you disagree with anything I did, feel free to [edit] again. Welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question!

Comment: @Vincent, you captured what I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Open your Layers and Channels palettes;
2. Make your image a regular layer as opposed to a background layer. Easiest way is to <kbd>double click</kbd> the layer bar in the Layers palette;
3. In the Channels palette, make sure the RGB channels are visible, then click the leftmost icon on the bottom, 'Load channel as selection';
4. In the Layers palette, click the 'Add Layer Mask' icon (third from left, rectangle with a round hole in it);
5. With the Layer Mask still selected, choose <kbd>Image > Adjustments > Invert</kbd>, shortcut <kbd>Control / Command</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>;
6. Use Layer Styles to give the layer a black Color Overlay;
7. Create a coloured layer under your current layer to see the effect;
8. Tweak the effect using opacity, curves or other adjustments on both the actual layer and the mask;
9. Save as png-24. Don't forget to turn off your coloured background layer before you do.